# Do I need a UK transit visa in addition to an Italian work permit to change terminals at LHR?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens, lhr

I am an Indian by nationality and have an Italian work permit (which corresponds to a residence permit). I am travelling back to India via London Heathrow Airport. I have a layover there for less than 24 hours, but I need to change terminals.

Do I need a UK transit visa? Will my residence permit from Italy help in getting a waiver for a UK transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

Changing terminals at Heathrow does not require you to pass the UK Border Control (there are buses) so you don't need a visa to enter the UK. The airport's website offers [connection guides](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/connection-guides) with the steps that will be required.

The Italian work permit could also exempt you from the Direct Airside Transit visa requirement, as explained on the [gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no):

> You won’t need a visa if you:
>
> - have a valid uniform format category D visa for entry to a state in the European Economic Area (EEA)
> - have a valid uniform format residence permit issued by an EEA state

A [uniform format visa from Italy looks like this](http://prado.consilium.europa.eu/en/3206/viewImage_75293.html) and a [uniform format residence permit like this](http://prado.consilium.europa.eu/en/4495/viewImage_118587.html).

If you do need to pass through the UK Border Control (e.g. to collect your luggage or stay the night in a hotel), you might also be able to get a “transit without visa concession” but that's left at the discretion of the border agent.